# Java https server

Tags: java, ssl, https, server, keystore

I am building an application server in Java using the HttpServer class. I have this server functioning perfectly using plain text communication over HTTP. However, I wish to upgrade this to using SSL, using the HttpsServer class.
I used this question as a basis to work from: [Simple Java HTTPS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308479/simple-java-https-server)

My server class is as follows:

```
public Server(Options options){

    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    try {
        server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        char[] password = options.getSSLPassword().toCharArray();
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance ("JKS");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (options.getSSLKeystore());
        ks.load ( fis, password );

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance ( "SunX509" );
        kmf.init ( ks, password );

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance ( "SunX509" );
        tmf.init ( ks );

        sslContext.init ( kmf.getKeyManagers (), tmf.getTrustManagers (), null );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    HttpsConfigurator httpsConfigurator = new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext) {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpsParameters httpsParameters) {
            SSLContext sslContext = getSSLContext();
            SSLParameters defaultSSLParameters = sslContext.getDefaultSSLParameters();
            httpsParameters.setSSLParameters(defaultSSLParameters);
        }
    };

   server.createContext("/", new HttpHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            HttpsExchange s = (HttpsExchange)t;
            s.getSSLSession();
            String response = "<html><body>Hello world.</body></html>";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    });
    server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    System.out.println("Starting server on port " + port + "...");
    server.setHttpsConfigurator(httpsConfigurator);
    server.start();
    System.out.println("Server started successfully!");
}
```

This compiles and runs fine, but then when I try to connect to through a browser on localhost:8080 I get "no data received" and on https://localhost:8080 I get "webpage is not available" 
There are no exceptions being thrown and it seems to run with no issues, apart from the fact that it just does nothing.

I used the keytool program to generate the keystore, however I am unfamiliar with this process so perhaps this is incorrect? But again, it accepts this as it is setting up the keystore and keyManagers etc.

Do I need to change my HttpHandler or contexts to handle an SSL exchange or something?

Comment: The fact that you didn't get a TLS handshake error indicates that the certificates etc aren't the problem. Does the same URL work with HTTP?

Comment: The same URL was working for HttpServer, rather than HttpsServer. Using a browser neither a https or http request work in its current state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been able to get the program working with SSL with the code I provided in my question. I believe the issue I was having was because of the keystore I had generated. Using this command to generate the keystore it worked:

```
keytool -genkey -alias alias -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 2048
```