# Java : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

Given the following code:

```
    public void start(String a_sAddress, int a_nPort) throws IOException {

    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {

            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,  String authType) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        } };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init( null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom() );

    //  Init a configuration with our SSL context
        HttpsConfigurator configurator = new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext);

       HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(a_sAddress, a_nPort), 0);

       server.setHttpsConfigurator(configurator);

       //here - attaching HttpHanlder code.

       server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
       server.start();
    }
    catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        System.out.println("HttpsRequest - setTLSMode - KeyManagementException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("HttpsRequest - setTLSMode - NoSuchAlgorithmException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I was trying to ignore certificate verification, since I am only a test simulator.

The problem is that my client gets "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake"

Must I handle certificates here? Or am I failing in trying to ignore the certificates validation?

Thank you.

---

Update: Well, talking to some friends, they suggested I should create a self-signed certificate, register my server with it and send it to my client to use when sending me requests.

My server is running on Solaris 10. I tried to look in 
[The Most Common Java Keytool Keystore Commands](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html)
 but couldn't figure out the specific commands which fits my needs. 
Can you please assist?
Thanks

Comment: you cannot create https server without _some_ private key for generate session keys for traffic encryption. You should pass keyManagers to sslContext with any valid private key at least. for example check this question answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308479/simple-java-https-server

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
keytool -genkey ...
```

to generate a keypair, and then

```
keytool -selfcert ...
```

to generate a self-signed certificate, using the same alias.