# JDK 11 PreMaster Secret debugging

Tags: java, ssl, wireshark, java-11

Using [this simple https server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794765/1674940) slightly modified to replace var with Java 8 compatible types, I can run it as such:

```
$ java8 -cp . -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,keygen javatester.SimpleHTTPSServer | grep Nonce -C 5
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: A7 7C E0 10 EB E5 7C 16   CF 70 65 30 04 AE 5B BC  .........pe0..[.
0010: 6F 61 52 6C FC 71 58 D9   F4 BD 10 70 69 10 62 2A  oaRl.qX....pi.b*
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: A3 E4 45 27 77 6C 0D 5E   BD F1 4E 9D 1E 2E 10 02  ..E'wl.^..N.....
0010: 7F 6E A1 EC C2 BC 40 E3   1E 32 A9 B9 13 3B 6C B5  .n....@..2...;l.
Server Nonce:
0000: 5E B5 99 F9 02 EE C3 9E   84 30 01 32 B4 04 BA 38  ^........0.2...8
0010: B1 D9 B2 D9 6E 54 F4 4C   BF DC 60 98 97 AD 8B B2  ....nT.L..`.....
Master Secret:
0000: D6 14 BF 8E FF 69 93 9C   DB 58 35 AC 65 EF 5B A2  .....i...X5.e.[.
0010: 79 D7 3D 67 76 F7 CA 82   69 F9 30 34 9A C8 E7 EB  y.=gv...i.04....
```

These values I can use to [create a Wireshark-capable premaster secret log file](https://timothybasanov.com/2016/05/26/java-pre-master-secret.html) to decode the connection. However, when I run this with jdk 11, I don't get any keygen output:

```
$ java11 -cp . -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,keygen javatester.SimpleHTTPSServer
Start single-threaded server at /0.0.0.0:8443
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:10.479 EDT|SSLCipher.java:437|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.367 EDT|SSLCipher.java:1824|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.369 EDT|SSLCipher.java:1978|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.382 EDT|X509Authentication.java:243|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.382 EDT|X509Authentication.java:243|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.382 EDT|X509Authentication.java:243|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.414 EDT|SSLCipher.java:1978|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.417 EDT|SSLCipher.java:1824|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.423 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1002|Closing output stream
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.423 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:670|close outbound of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.424 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:877|Closing input stream
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.425 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:636|close inbound of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.425 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:473|duplex close of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-05-08 13:51:24.425 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1381|close the SSL connection (passive)
```

I wondered if this was no longer supported, but the help command suggests it is:

```
$ java11 -cp . -Djavax.net.debug=help javatester.SimpleHTTPSServer
(...snipped)
ssl            turn on ssl debugging

The following can be used with ssl:
        record       enable per-record tracing
        handshake    print each handshake message
        keygen       print key generation data
        session      print session activity
(snipped...)
```

How can I export the premaster secret from jdk11 connections so I can use them in Wireshark?

Comment: Java 11 supports TLS 1.3. may be one of the changes for TLS 1.3 also affects the pre-master secret and therefore it is not printed anymore? I would limit the server to s specific set of TLS version(s) and cipher suite(s) to make it comparable. Alternatively you may try this [project](https://github.com/neykov/extract-tls-secrets) to get the pre-master keys.

Comment: That project works, if you make it an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the newer Java versions do no longer output the pre-master secret you can use the project [extract-tls-secrets](https://github.com/neykov/extract-tls-secrets).

> Decrypt HTTPS/TLS connections on-the-fly. Extract the shared secrets from secure TLS connections for use with Wireshark. Attach to a Java process on either side of the connection to start decrypting.

The code of this project can be injected at start-up into the TLS server or client using the `javaagent` system, or you can connect to an existing Java process (I assume via Java debugger interface).

Comment: Confirmed this still works with Java 21