# How to add the intermediate certificate within Java HTTPSServer

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I already added the certificate for my domain to a java keystore and followed this answer to set up my HTTPSServer: [Simple Java HTTPS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308479/simple-java-https-server). Now I want to add my intermediate certificate too. I have the .cer file of it but I don't know how I can add it, so that my server can find and use it.
Previously I added the certificate by converting it with the `openssl` command and then using the `keytool` command to import it to my keystore, but that doesn't work for the intermediate certificate.

Comment: If you dislike command-line utils you can just use https://keystore-explorer.org. It allows to import certificates into keystore using a nice GUI.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped me.

Comment: BTW: I am hoping that with "a java keystore" you mean a newly created keystore and not the trust-keystore that comes with Java. Modifying the keystore that comes with Java is possible but very bad style and should be avoided.

Comment: Yes, I mean a newly created one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by appending the intermediate certificate to my certificate in the [keystore explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org). Thanks to [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150978/robert).
[image: Keystore Explorer]