# Serve https with Jersey 1

Tags: java, rest, https, jersey

I'm trying to update an old RESTful API to allow it to serve https; I don't actually need the added security but I've got clients complaining about mixed context - this is on a deployed desktop application that is just using REST to communicate; not a deployed web app.

This is a jersey 1 implementation and I'm trying to avoid having to upgrade to Jersey 2.  The HTTP serving was very easy:

```
this.server = HttpServerFactory.create(baseUri, 
                new DefaultResourceConfig(DataPaqResource.class));
```

So I've looked around and pulled from the javadocs the following to start https or http based on the base uri passed in:

```
StartWebServer(String baseUri) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException{
    ResourceListeners.addDataPaqResourceListener(this);

    if (baseUri.startsWith("https")) {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance ("SSL");
        this.server = (HttpsServer) HttpServerFactory.create(baseUri, 
            new DefaultResourceConfig(DataPaqResource.class));
        ((HttpsServer) this.server).setHttpsConfigurator (new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext) {
            public void configure (HttpsParameters params) {
                SSLContext c = getSSLContext();

                // get the default parameters
                SSLParameters sslparams = c.getDefaultSSLParameters();
                 
                params.setSSLParameters(sslparams);
            }
        });
    }else {
        this.server = HttpServerFactory.create(baseUri, 
            new DefaultResourceConfig(DataPaqResource.class));
    }
    System.out.println("Started web server on " + baseUri + " imp " + 
        this.server.getClass().getName());
}
```

This works fine for http but with https I get:

Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

This error is from postman but obviously browsers fail too.  Basically I know that the https is configured incorrectly but I'm not sure how to configure it.  I don't need the security; I just need to be able to serve https with the minimal amount of configuration.

Any and all help gratefully received!

Comment: Updated to use code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308479/simple-java-https-server.  This does trigger the configure method but I still get the same error on the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - it was basically all working except I loaded the keystore wrong!

```
//keystore generated with
//keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -alias self_signed -keypass datapaq -keystore 
//datapaq.keystore -storepass datapaq
public class StartWebServer implements DataPaqResourceListener{

private HttpServer server;
private static final String password = "datapaq";

StartWebServer(String baseUri) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException{
    ResourceListeners.addDataPaqResourceListener(this);
    if (baseUri.startsWith("https")) {
        
        this.server = (HttpsServer) HttpServerFactory.create(baseUri, 
                new DefaultResourceConfig(DataPaqResource.class));
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance ("SSL");

        KeyStore ks = getKeyStore();

        // Set up the key manager factory
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(ks, password.toCharArray());
        
        // Set up the trust manager factory
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);
        
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        
        // Set up the HTTPS context and parameters
        ((HttpsServer) this.server).setHttpsConfigurator (new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext) {
             public void configure (HttpsParameters params) {
                 try {
                        // Initialise the SSL context
                        SSLContext context = getSSLContext();
                        SSLEngine engine = context.createSSLEngine();
                        engine.setNeedClientAuth(false);
                        engine.setWantClientAuth(false);
                        params.setNeedClientAuth(false);
                        params.setWantClientAuth(false);
                        params.setCipherSuites(engine.getEnabledCipherSuites());
                        params.setProtocols(engine.getEnabledProtocols());

                       // Set the SSL parameters
                        SSLParameters sslParameters = context.getSupportedSSLParameters();
                        params.setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
             }
         });
    }else {
        this.server = HttpServerFactory.create(baseUri, 
                new DefaultResourceConfig(DataPaqResource.class));
    }
}

private KeyStore getKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    // Initialise the keystore
    char[] password = "datapaq".toCharArray();
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("datapaq.keystore");
    ks.load(fis, password);
    return ks;

}
}
```